# Query MySQL para contar contratos com INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

Olá,

relacionando as seguintes tabelas:

**Tabela Contrato**

```
tb_contrato
id
credor_id
num_contrato
```

**Tabela Fatura**

```
tb_fatura
id
contrato_id
num_fatura
dt_vencimento
valor
```

**Parâmetros**

```
credor  = 1
valor inicial  = 1
valor final = 99999
atraso inicial = 1
atraso final = 99999
```

**Query**

```
SELECT `contrato`.`num_contrato`
FROM `tb_contrato` `contrato`
JOIN `tb_fatura` `fatura` ON `fatura`.`contrato_id` = `contrato`.`id`
WHERE `tb_fatura`.`valor` >= valor_inicial
AND `tb_fatura`.`valor` <= valor_final
```

utilizando os parâmetros, preciso contar a quantidade de contratos de acordo com a query acima, tambem preciso entender como posso filtrar os contratos utilizando os dias em atraso do contrato, comparando a data de vencimento da fatura com a data de hoje!

Comment: Em sua query um contrato será listado mais de uma vez se possuir mais de uma fatura que atenda as condições. Para contar os contratos distintos você deve utilizar a função COUNT com a cláusula DISTINCT, mas não tenho plena certeza de que é isso o que deseja.

Comment: Isso é exatamente o que está acontecendo, está listando um para cada fatura e não é isso que eu quero. o que realmente é quero listar apenas a quantidade de contratos que se enquedre nos paramentros da consulta.

Comment: Sim, é o que se espera do resultado de um INNER JOIN.

Comment: Pode me ajudar a construír a querie ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conforme citado nos comentários, para saber a quantidade de contatos, basta fazer um count distinct com base no numero do contrato. Aqui tem um exemplo

```
SELECT count(distinct `contrato`.`num_contrato`) as total_contratos
FROM `tb_contrato` `contrato`
JOIN `tb_fatura` `fatura` ON `fatura`.`contrato_id` = `contrato`.`id`
WHERE `bill`.`valor` between valor_inicial AND valor_final
```

A tabela de fatura não tem um campo para dizer se pagou ou não. Para ver uma contagem dos registros cuja data de vencimento é menor do que a data atual, pode ser feito o seguinte:

```
SELECT count(distinct `contrato`.`num_contrato`) as total_contratos
FROM `tb_contrato` `contrato`
JOIN `tb_fatura` `fatura` ON `fatura`.`contrato_id` = `contrato`.`id`
WHERE `bill`.`valor` between valor_inicial AND valor_final
AND `fatura`.`dt_vencimento` < CURRENT_DATE()
```

Para retornar registros com uma certa quantidade de dias em atraso, pode ser utilizada a função DATEDIFF . Aqui tem exemplos:

http://jquerydicas.blogspot.com/2013/11/mysql-diferenca-entre-datas.html

Answer (score 1):

Como esclarecido nos comentários:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `contrato`.`num_contrato`
FROM `tb_contrato` `contrato`
JOIN `tb_fatura` `fatura` ON `fatura`.`contrato_id` = `contrato`.`id`
WHERE `bill`.`valor` >= valor_inicial
AND `bill`.`valor` <= valor_final
```

para listar os diferentes contratos que atendam as condições, e:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `contrato`.`num_contrato`)
FROM `tb_contrato` `contrato`
JOIN `tb_fatura` `fatura` ON `fatura`.`contrato_id` = `contrato`.`id`
WHERE `bill`.`valor` >= valor_inicial
AND `bill`.`valor` <= valor_final
```

para a quantidade de contratos que atendam as condições.